# Consulta MySQL únicamente del registro que más se repite

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría recibir ayuda con una consulta que me traiga solo el registro que se repite más en una columna de una tabla `mysql`.

| columnaNombre |
| --- |
| maria |
| maria |
| maria |
| carlos |
| cralos |
| luisa |

Tráeme la consulta de que María es el registro que más se repite, pero únicamente del que más se repite. No todos como con order by  ni nada por el estilo.

NO ME REFIERO A ALGO COMO ESTO

```
SELECT columnName, COUNT (columnaNombre) FROM tablaNombre GROUP BY columnaNombre
```

Me refiero a algo como esto, pero sin tener que filtrarlo

```
SELECT Candidato, COUNT (Candidato) AS FROM votantes FROM Candidato = 'John'
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask], sobre todo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), esto haría que las respuestas fueran más de tú agrado.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con esto

```
SELECT candidato, COUNT(*)
FROM votantes
GROUP BY candidato 
ORDER BY candidato DESC
LIMIT 1
```

o si quieres obtener el dato con otro nombre

```
SELECT candidato, COUNT(*) AS candidatoMasVotado
FROM votantes
GROUP BY candidato 
ORDER BY candidatoMasVotado DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No me funciona solo me trae el registro con mas letras

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción:

```
SELECT columnName,COUNT(*)
  FROM tablaNombre
  GROUP BY columnaNombre
  HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
        SELECT columnName,COUNT(*) n
          FROM tablaNombre
          GROUP BY columnaNombre  
    ) c1  
  );
```

El alias `c1` es el de la subconsulta y el `n` el de la columna que contabiliza los nombres. Es necesario usarlos en SQL.

Con esta subconsulta obtienes la relación de las veces que aparece cada nombre:

```
        SELECT columnName,COUNT(*) n
          FROM tablaNombre
          GROUP BY columnaNombre
```

Con ésta otra, el número máximo de veces que aparece un nombre:

```
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
    ) c1
```

Y, con la última, identificas a qué registro corresponde ese número de veces:

```
SELECT columnName,COUNT(*)
  FROM tablaNombre
  GROUP BY columnaNombre
  HAVING COUNT(*)=(
  );
```

Comment: perfecta, aunque no entiendo aun lo consulta, porque n y porque c1.

Comment: podrías explicar la consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ok, amplío la respuesta, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es hacer una agrupación de la columna objetivo, sumar el contador y luego devolver el mayor resultado.

```sql
SELECT CANDIDATO, COUNT(CANDIDATO) AS MAYOR_VOTADO # Obtenemos el candidato y su repetición
FROM VOTANTES
GROUP BY CANDIDATO # Agrupamos los resultados por el nombre
ORDER BY MAYOR_VOTADO DESC # Ordenamos los resultados por el contador de forma descendiente
LIMIT 1 # Y devolvemos el último.
```

He probado la query en una web online que emula MySQL y ha funcionado bien, por lo que no debería darte problemas.